# Is the statement $\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j<\infty,~(x_j\ge0)$ $\Longrightarrow \lim _{k \to \infty} \sum_{j=k}^\infty x_j=0$ true?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, riemann-sum

As the title states, I would like to know if the statement
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_{j}<\infty \Longrightarrow \lim _{k \to \infty} \sum_{j=k}^{\infty} x_{j}=0,\qquad x_j\in [0,\infty)
$$
is always true?

**Edit:**

My confusion came from the following proof of convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left\langle x, e_{j}\right\rangle e_{j}
$$
(we are working in a Hilbert space, and the vectors $\{e_j\}$ are orthonormal.) Let $m,k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
\begin{gathered}
\left\|\sum_{j=1}^{m+k}\left\langle x, e_{j}\right\rangle e_{j}-\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left\langle x, e_{j}\right\rangle e_{j}\right\|^{2}=\left\|\sum_{j=m+1}^{m+k}\left\langle x, e_{j}\right\rangle e_{j}\right\|^{2} \\
=\sum_{j=m+1}^{m+k}\left|\left\langle x, e_{j}\right\rangle\right|^{2} \leq \sum_{j=m+1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle x, e_{j}\right\rangle\right|^{2}
\end{gathered}
$$
We know that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle x, e_{j}\right\rangle\right|^{2}<\infty$ and it follows that
$$
\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=m+1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle x, e_{j}\right\rangle\right|^{2}=0
$$

Comment: You may want to modify the hypothesis to  "$\sum_{j =1}^{\infty} x_j$ convergent" ; then all is OK

Comment: Assume that $\sum_{j\geq 1}x_j = c < +\infty$ and let $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j$. The convergence of the series is equivalent to the convergence of the sequence $\{S_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, and convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ are also Cauchy sequences, meaning that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $M_\varepsilon$ such that $n,m\geq M_{\varepsilon}$ implies $|S_n-S_m|<\varepsilon$. In particular the tails $\sum_{j\geq k}x_j = c-S_{k-1}$ are automatically convergent to zero.

Comment: I will modify the post

Comment: @Logi nm -- I read it wrong

Comment: Without the assumption that the $x_j$ are non-negative, the implication is false or insensible.  For example one might have $x_j = (-1)^j$, an alternating series whose partial sums are bounded.  If the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_{j}$ is not convergent, it would be important to define what is meant by saying it is less than infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

Let $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j,~x_j\ge0$, since $S_n$ is non-decreasing and bounded above, the partial sum is convergent, $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=S$, hence, the series is convergent.

$$S=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j+\sum_{j=n}^\infty x_j=S_n+T_n\Rightarrow T_n=S-S_n$$

Since $T_n$ is non-increasing and bounded below $T_n\ge0$, hence, $T_n$ is convergent.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}S-\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=S-S=0$$

Comment: $\sum_{j\geq k}(-1)^j$ is not a number, so it does not make sense to consider the limit of such expression as $k\to +\infty$. I guess that the premises mean that $\sum_{j\geq 1}x_j$ is convergent, not that its partial sums are bounded.

Comment: Yes, the limit doesn't exist. So the OP is false. Let's wait if the author will modify the OP. @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: I personally disagree that this is a valid example, simply because you can't say the summation is less than $\infty$ if it can't be assigned a value in the first place.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in the OP when write $<\infty$, what I interpret is bounded @PrincessEev

Comment: Note that the ambiguity is fixed by OP's edit of $x_j \geq 0$.

Comment: Please see the modified post. Maybe it is easier to answer when you know where my confusion comes from.

Comment: ok, I have edited, thank you. @BrianMoehring

Comment: Yes, I have edited it, thank you @Logi

Comment: @MathFail, Thank you, I see it now.

Comment: you are most welcome! @Logi